# Preprocessor flag as bool input parameter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a method in objective-c that takes the parameter `advertisement:(BOOL)advertisement`. I'm wanting to send in a preprocessor "LITE_VERSION" as the parameter and if it exists I want it to return `YES`, and if it doesn't `NO`. Is there some safe way to accomplish this without having to write anymore code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be looking at something like:

```
#ifdef LITE_VERSION
    return YES;
#else
    return NO;
#endif
```

This would effectively harcode one of those two `return` statements at compile time based on `LITE_VERSION`.

Or you can make it even simpler if you can guarantee you'll set `LITE_VERSION` to a specific value of either `YES` or `NO`:

```
return LITE_VERSION;
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess you can't do the first block of code you listed on one line as a parameter?

Comment: @StackOverFlowRider, you possibly _could_ with a little trickery, but is it really necessary?